# Append returning None

Tags: python

Was having trouble figuring out why self.Curr returns None. I now learned that append edits a list and returns None.  However, my goal was for PrevList / prev to remain unchanged and have self.Curr be the new appended list.  Can anyone explain what is going on and suggest how I can assign self.Curr to the new appended list while keeping PrevList / prev unchanged?

```
class AssignmentNode:
    def __init__(self,asmt,prev):
        self.Asmt = asmt
        self.PrevList = prev

        self.Curr = prev.append(asmt)

AssignmentNode("A",[])
```

I even tried...

```
c = prev.append(asmt)
self.Curr = c
```

...but that did not work either.

Comment: Either `self.Curr = prev + [asmt]` or `c = prev.copy()` followed by `c.append(asmt)` and `self.Curr = c`

Comment: By the way, @JulienBernu - I use PhraseExpress to easily reproduce canned posts. You can also use something like AutoHotkey or other macro/text expander languages/programs.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: found a better one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That certainly is a better one. :)